# Reaction forces in electrodynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics

Consider two conducting plates, at different potentials so as to set up an electric field. A charged particle is released in the field. The particle experiences a force for sure, but is there a reaction force on the plates, we may have failed to notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as if you throw a ball in the gravitational field of the Earth.  Every *action force* has a *reaction force*, equally strong.  But the Earth doesn't move much, since it is much more massive than your ball.  Same for a charge between the conducting plates.

Comment: so linear momentum can be conserved?

Comment: Yes, linear momentum of the whole system is conserved, *if there is no external agent acting on the whole*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed. The plates experience an equal and opposite reaction force. It's not like this force has been unnoticed, we just consider the plates to be held fixed.